# Determine which dataset is blocking a firedac connection

Tags: delphi-10-seattle, firedac

I have a single threaded Firedac (SQL Server) application that is sometimes producing the error below.

> Connection is busy with results for another hstmt.

This error mostly happens on queries that are run on a timer (TTimer). Is there a way of asking the FDConnection which dataset is blocking the connection?

I have scoured my code looking for TFDQueries that do not fetch all data or  have AutoClose set to False. We do allow multiple recordsets (using NextRecordSet) so maybe this is causing this error?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to update MSSQL Native client. I got the same error and installing the last version of the native client resolved it.

Comment: Thanks Alexander, didn't have the SQL driver on my radar, was thinking it was Firedac. Will get the clients to upgrade and see how I go.